# Please help me with this regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I am trying to search inputs with the required ids.But it seems my regular expression is incorrect. Please help me to correct it. And also please suggest me to improve coding standards.
I will have inputs with ids like.. a1_1,b1_1,c3_999,d4_777 etc... Those will be there inside a `<td>`.
What i want is i need to some inputs with the passed ids.
Like

```
   NoneArray=[a_1,c_3].
```

So i need to find these ids and assign a Class. For that i am using below code..

http://jsfiddle.net/nnQxN/

```
for(var i = 0;i < NoneArray.length;i++)
{
    var x = NoneArray[i]+"_";
    $('input').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).prop('id').match(^[''+x+''][0-9]{})
    }).addClass('xve');
}
```

Please help me on this. Or please suggest me any another way using `pushstack` and `map` functions.

Comment: You can try this RegEx generator http://txt2re.com/ if you are not sure you did it right.

Comment: can you provide some sample input and sample output ur expecting?

Comment: Ya Shekhar, I have given jsfiddle link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use a ["starts with"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector. I'm not sure how your HTML is structured but if the things you're searching for are all inside a `<div id="container">`, then:

```
var NoneArray = ['a1', 'c3'];
$.each(NoneArray, function(i, pat) {
    $('#container').find('[id^=' + pat + '_]').addClass('xve');
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/MwqyS/

If you're just looking for `<input>` elements then this should work:

```
var NoneArray = ['a1', 'c3'];
$.each(NoneArray, function(i, pat) {
    $('input[id^=' + pat + '_]').addClass('xve');
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tDTjh/